# How to create subroutine in mysql perl with variables

Tags: mysql, perl, hash, subroutine

I have two mysql commands. I want to create a subroutine with these two mysql commands for the rest of my data that I have to search through. I have a lot of entries. Is there a way to create a subroutine such that in place of the actual numbers and characters I put in my two mysql commands, I put in variables that I can replace so I can then copy and paste the actual values of those variables and the commands are executed for the remaining entries?

For example, I have a command that says

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare ("select name from table1 where number > 5");
$sth->execute();
@row;
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
print "$row[0]\tquestion1\n";
```

In place of the "5" listed in the select command and "question1" listed in the print command, I want to put something in place of it like "variables" so that I can create a subroutine with these commands in it, but you execute and can run the subroutine over and over by plugging in different values for those variables.

something like this: $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password);
not sure how to go about doing this for mysql perl.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) in your query to use different values in a search.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare ("select name from table1 where number > ?");
$sth->execute(5);
```

After that, it should be trivial to make a subroutine for your print.

For example:

```
my @values = qw(5 10 15 20);
my @fields = qw(question1 question2);
# ... other code..
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ("select name from table1 where number > ?");

for my $field (@fields) {
    for my $value (@values) {
        printfields($sth, $value, $field);
    }
}

sub printfields {
    my ($sth, $value, $field) = @_;
    $sth->execute($value);
    while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
        print "$row[0]\t$field\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to manually enter the values from notepad into the placeholders, but I'm using this information from notepad entries to sort through a mysql table. Is there anyway to create a command to run the subroutine so I can just copy and paste into the command the values to go into the placeholders?

Comment: Notepad? How horrible. Copy/paste sounds even worse. What prevents you from simply reading the information from a file directly? Its difficult to recommend anything without knowing exactly what your input looks like.

Comment: Yes, I Should clarify more. I have a table of > 170,000 genes in mysql. In notepad, I have a list consisting of 4 columns: reg. element,  and their chromosome, start position, end position. I made mysql command for perl to find gene in mysql table nearest each reg. element. Now I have to find nearest genes for the rest of reg. elements listed in notepad - and there are a lot of them.

Comment: Well, its easy enough to load a file into perl. Just `open` the file, `split` the line accordingly to extract the columns (or use a proper parser for your file format) and insert those values into your query.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to build the select query before running prepare().  Then passing it into prepare() as a scalar.  You could also add placeholders in the scalar (if you don't want to simply rebuild it for each query) that could easily be replaced via calls of s///;, which could be easily named/identified as well.  This would make the code a bit easier to read than passing bare values to execute().